# Escape regular expression

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have an xml file with regular expression. When I read it, I get an expression `<a class="call-to-action-details".*?\shref="(.*?)"` in a variable called `regex`.

Then I call my string method: `print(text.searchRegex(regex))` and it returns nothing.

But if I call my regex method and escape some characters, then it returns results:

```
print(text.searchRegex("<a class=\"call-to-action-details\".*?\\shref=\"(.*?)\""))
```

How do I escape characters? Or what do i did wrong? My regexSearch function:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex,
        options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let nstext = text as NSString
    let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nstext.length)
    var matches: Array<String> = Array<String>()
    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(text,
            options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0),
            range: all) {
        (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
        let theResult = nstext.substringWithRange(result!.rangeAtIndex(1))
        matches.append(theResult)
    }
    print(matches)
    return matches.joinWithSeparator("")
} catch {
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling `escapedPatternForString:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a string literal, the backslash (`\`) and the double quote (`"`) need to be escaped by using a backslash.

It’s probably also a bad idea to use the same name of `regex` for your pattern string as the resulting `NSRegularExpression`.

**When reading the regular expression from a file, you do not need to escape the characters as in a literal.** The expression of

```
<a class="call-to-action-details".*?\shref="(.*?)"
```

can be used directly by `NSRegularExpression` when read in from a file.

If you are not getting a match with the regex in the file, try checking for equality of your working regex literal and the string you are reading in. There may be an extra character somewhere that is causing them to not match.

Other than that, your code will grab the match without a problem.